# How can I exchange data between android phones and Intel Edison constantly?

Tags: javascript, android, intel-xdk, intel-edison

I need to connect several android devices to an Intel Edison via WiFi or blueetooth (WiFi prefered), i'm using the XDK IDE (javascript) for my project, but i can't find a proper example to do this, the devices will act as sensors and will send data to the Edison board constantly, then the program on the board will do some calculations and will send back information.

Comment: Why aren't the examples right for your situation? Eg. like this one: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/connecting-to-intel-edison-from-android-with-bluetooth-le-ble

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Wifi, I would suggest that you use a lightweight messaging protocol, e.g. AMQP or MAQTT.

They work in a producer-broker-consumer model and the broker relays messages based on the topic selected by the producer and consumers.

If I am right, Intel Edison has a built-in Mosquito MQTT broker. The client (consumer) can also be set up on the board. If you search the web, you can easily find ready-made MQTT Android clients as well.